# ASP.NET Membership Webforms redirection when using IE

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, webforms

I've got an issue whereby when a user logs into a website using Firefox, it works.
When the user logs in using internet explorer, it doesn't work. I've checked and tried compatibility mode, and that doesn't make any difference.

Does anyone have any idea why when using IE, it would redirect back to the login page, but it doesn't happen on firefox or chrome?

Thoughts?

[image: Loading, and redirecting back to the login screen]

Comment: Looks like it doesn't think you are authenticated or you don't have proper permissions. Is the auth cookie getting set ?

Comment: Cookie gets set, user gets redirected to page Client/Dashboard/Default.aspx, from there, its like they get redirected back to the login page. Remember that this works in firefox and chrome - it only happens using internet explorer.

Comment: What does debugging show you as the reason why it is sent back to login page?  It still sounds like IE isn't accepting cookies. Have you verified it can identify the user after login in ie?

Comment: It works fine on my local machine. It's only happening once published and deployed to the server.

Comment: That is odd. Have you cleared out IE cooked and tried logging in again? That's happened to me in IE before.

Comment: its happening for myself, and many other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was reboot the server completely and it started working again.

That was so strange.